# What should be structure of service layer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, architecture

**Background Information:** I am trying to implement my server with separate Controller, Service and Dao layers. I am not sure how the Service layer module should be organized.

For example, let's consider a `UserService` module, which is a sub module in the service layer module. However, I don't want to create a single `UserService` file, but rather divide it into individual files, for example, a `FetchUsers` class which is part of User service and will have different methods for fetching users, like `filterBySomething(params)` which will include some business logic as well, so they need to be in service layer.

If I don't divide the 'UserService' into separate modules, there will be too much stuff in a single one and it will violate SRP as well.

**Question:** I can think of two ways of achieving this, which one is better? If there are better ways than these two or I should not be trying to achieve this, please suggest alternatives.

Method 1:

```
- services
  - user
    - index.js - directly exports modules inside user service
    - FetchUser
    - CreateUser

The index.js will do something like this:
FetchUser = require('./FetchUser');
module.exports = {
  FetchUser: FetchUser
}

Controller will use it as:
UserService.FetchUser.filterBySomething()
```

Method 2:

```
- services
  - user
    - index.js - exports methods of individual modules, not the modules themselves
    - FetchUser
    - CreateUser

The index.js will do something like this:
FetchUser = require('./FetchUser');
module.exports = {
  filterBySomething: FetchUser.filterBySomething
}

Controller will use it as:
UserService.filterBySomething()
```

Method 1 looks like it does not have enough encapsulation. Method 2 has good encapsulation, but it requires me to maintain the index.js inside user service whenever I want to add/remove anything from any file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**method 2** seems good as you say, because of encapsulation.

Another method that could save you a lot of time is to **automate the export** in index.js
*(which would be the same index.js for any Service, and be self updated each time you change/add a module in the same directory and restart your server)*

I'm not an expert of code optimization, but this works

```js
// index.js (for ALL services)
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

let fileNames = fs.readdirSync('.')
// use Sync to not create Async errors elsewere
  .filter(name => name.endsWith('.js') && name !== __filename)
  // only get js files and exclude this file
  .map(name => './' + path.relative(__dirname, name))
  // get relative paths

let methods = {}
// the future export of this file

fileNames.forEach(file => {
  try {
    let fileModule = require(file) 
    // try to require the module
    Object.keys(fileModule).forEach(method => {
    // for each method/key of the module
      methods[method] = fileModule[method]
      // add this method to the exports of this file (methods)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('WARNING:\n' + err.message)
    // probably couldn't require the module
  }
})

module.exports = methods
// you export all the exported methods
// of all the js files of the same directory
```

*Obviously, you should export only "public" methods in each of your modules*

```js
class FetchUser {
  static filterBySomething (arg) {
    // do your magik
  }
  static method2 (arg) {
    // another method
  }
}

module.exports = FetchUser
// this will make ALL methods of class FetchUser accessible in index

module.exports = {
  filterBySomething: FetchUser.filterBySomething
}
// if you want other methods like method2 to NOT be exported
```